# Отследить что пишеться и читается из /dev/mem определенной программой

Tags: linux

У меня есть конкретная задача, узнать как программа общается с контроллером и повторить это.
Есть linux с написанной програмой на xilinx Zynq. С помощью strace я узнал что программа работает с портами читая и записывая в `/dev/mem`. Подскажите как мне точно узнать что читает и что записывает программа туда? Куда копать?

Это часть `strace`. Это единственный системный файл который открывает программа. В результате открытия `/dev/mem` получается `0xb6f8b000`. И дальше этого лога не используется.

```
open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)    = 4
mmap2(NULL, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 4, 0xf8000000) = 
0xb6f8b000
brk(0)                                  = 0x7c8000
brk(0x7ca000)                           = 0x7ca000
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7ab70}, {SIG_DFL, [], 
0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7ab70}, {SIG_DFL, [], 
0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
pipe2([5, 6], O_CLOEXEC)                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], [CHLD], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0xbebb0f60, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_VFORK|SIGCHLD) = 
28506
close(6)                                = 0
read(5, "", 4)                          = 0
close(5)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
wait4(28506, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 28506
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7ab70}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7ab70}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=28506, 
si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
munmap(0xb6f8b000, 65536)               = 0
close(4)
```

При попытки дизасемблировать программу получается такое:

```
root@debian:/home/l# file work_s
work_s: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), too many section (65535)


root@debian:/home/l# readelf -h work_s
ELF Header:
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Class:                             ELF32
Data:                              2's complement, little endian
Version:                           1 (current)
OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU
ABI Version:                       0
Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
Machine:                           ARM
Version:                           0x1
Entry point address:               0xd984c
Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers:          65535 (bytes into file)
Flags:                             0x5000002, Version5 EABI, <unknown>
Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
Number of program headers:         3
Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
Number of section headers:         65535
Section header string table index: 65535 (187120167)
readelf: Error: Reading 0x27ffd8 bytes extends past end of file for section headers


root@debian:/home/l# /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/objdump -d work_s
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/objdump: work_s: File truncated
```

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Начальные значения можно, конечно, вытащить, запустив под gdb. Но дальше, в процессе работы отладчик все тайминги поломает...

Comment: дык, тем же `strace`'ом и посмотри...

Comment: @Fat-Zer: не получается увидеть куда именно пишет, и с `-y` `-yy` `-f` `-ff` пробовал. Могу видеть как записывает лог и ничего больше....

Comment: @CJ1, куда — это на какое смещение? там же `write()`'ами пишется, я правильно понимаю? тогда смещение должно быть видно в предыдущем `lseek()`'е...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Суть такая, я проанализировал все строки, что я вижу. Открывается /dev/mem/ Затем делается mmap2, затем munmap, затем close. Добавлю код в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Так как взаимодействие с файлом `/dev/mem` осуществляется через `mmap`, то следить вам нужно не за файловым вводом-выводом, а операциями записи/чтения памяти.

Запустите программу под gdb и поставьте брейкпоинты на доступ к памяти, указатель на которую вернул `mmap`: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html

Через gdb вы сможете видеть, что именно пишет программа, и что она читает.

Но я сразу вам скажу - приключений вы огребёте.

Comment: Зачем так сложно? Можно же просто в ядро вставить тестовую точку (через `perf`), и это покажет вам все обращения с нужными параметрами и т.п.

Comment: @0andriy никогда не пользовался, поэтому не могу ничего сказать. Что же касается вопроса ТС, то у меня сложилось впечатление, что приложение работает напрямую с PCI шиной, в обход ядра. Поэтому следить нужно напрямую за операциями с PCI IO address space

Comment: Да скорее всего, это же наверняка FPGA, а железячники писать программы конечно же не умеют :-(.